# How to access current state of redux store in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      return action.payload
    },
    setLoggedUser(state, action) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        'loggedBlogappUser',
        JSON.stringify(action.payload)
      )
    },
    getLoggedUser() {
      const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser')
      if (loggedUserJSON) {
        return JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      }
    },
  },
})
```

This is my loginReducer. i am dispatching getLoggedUser() so that when the logged in user comes back to that page, it stays logged in. But i want to assign token to create or update details.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLoggedUser())
    blogService.setToken(user.token)
  }, [])
```

This is my useEffect. after dispatching how can i access details inside loggedBlogappUser

I did tried to access the user details from the store several times.